# Windows Phone 8. Ip configuration

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, network-protocols, ipconfig

How I can get network parameters (ip4, ip6, mask, gateway) for all available interfaces in `WindowsPhone 8`? As like `ipconfig`. I found how I can do it with `Iphlpapi`, but I can not find it in `WP8`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find whether a network is using IPv4 or v6 on WP8 using properties of `HostName` (MSDN reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br207113.aspx)). The `IPInformation` property of `HostName` should contain what you are looking for. However it won't tell you the network gateway that I can see.

You can get a list of the current networks which are active from `Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation.GetHostNames()` (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.connectivity.networkinformation.gethostnames.aspx) - it's a bit of a pain to navigate between both references).